# Setting up a recurrence for Odd-Even Mergesort

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, sorting

Given the below algorithm
[image]

How would one go about setting up a recurrence for both that merging algorithm AND using this "new" merging algorithm in a traditional merge sort?

**What I've tried**

For the merge algorithm, I've concluded that the recurrence is $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + (n-1)$ or $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n$. I suspect this is my first error.

When combining it with the traditional merge sort, $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n$, we'd want to remove the $+n$ because we're going to replace it with our own merge. This new recurrence is $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 2T(n/2) + n = 4T(n/2) + n$. According to the Master's theorem, this yields a running time of $O(n^{log_2 4})$ which is $O(n^2)$. I know this isn't correct, because I already happen to know that the running time of an odd-even merge sort is $O(n log n)$.

Comment: You're trying to derive two _different_ functions there -- one for the time it takes to _merge_ two list of $n$ elements each, and one for the time it takes to _sort_ $n$ elements. When you notate both of them with the same letter $T$, you're creating hopeless confusion that invalidates most of what you're doing.

Comment: Don't I need the recurrence of the merge in order to get the recurrence of the new merge sort?

Comment: x @throw: Yes, but they are still two different functions. You can't name them both $T$ and expect things to make sense.

Comment: @HenningMakholm What would be the right way to do this then? I have no clue how to combine them if they're different. I've been told that once I figure out the recurrence for the merge algorithm, the merge sort algorithm will come naturally.

Comment: x @throw: The right way to do it would be to **use two different names for the two different functions**. (It is unclear to me how this is a difficult concept). Then solve the recurrences one by one -- since the merge operation is used as part of the sorting algorithm you need to solve its recurrence _before_ you can plug the solution into the other recurrence and start solving _that_.